# @ModelAttribute that depends from the ActionRequest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay-6

with Spring MVC Portlet I need in the modelattribute to retrieve the information from a service that depends from the ActionRequest (liferay 6.1.1).

I've tried this:

```
@ActionMapping(params="myaction=editUser")
    public void editUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") UserInfo user, BindingResult bindingResult,
                                        ActionResponse response, SessionStatus sessionStatus, ActionRequest request)
            throws Exception {

        myEditUserValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);

    //...
}

@ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserInfo getUser(@RequestParam String uid, ActionRequest request) throws Exception {
        return ldapService.getUser(uid, getVirtualPortalLdapMapping(request, virtualPortals));
}
```

but the error is:

```
ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:559] Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
Failed to invoke handler method [public void com.mystuff.portlets.controllers.EditUserController.editUser(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.portlet.ActionResponse,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.portlet.ActionRequest)
throws java.lang.Exception]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

Any idea? Thank you for any help

Comment: Your invoker expects your method to have 6 parameters: Model,String,BindingResult,ActionResponse,SessionStatus, and ActionRequest.  And your method declaration has only 5 parameters: UserInfo user, BindingResult bindingResult, ActionResponse response, SessionStatus sessionStatus, ActionRequest request.
Can you paste your UserInfo class?

Comment: Thank you, this was the reason (I was looking to an old error...)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your Model Attribute wrongly. **value** should not be there.

```
public void editUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserInfo user, BindingResult bindingResult,
ActionResponse response, SessionStatus sessionStatus, ActionRequest request)
```